# custom draggable icon in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, draggable

```
package com.example.drag_drop_practice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

private ImageView mImageView;
private ViewGroup mRrootLayout;
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRrootLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root);
    mImageView = (ImageView) mRrootLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
    mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    mImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
        _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
        layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        break;
    }
    mRrootLayout.invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

The icon in the app is draggable from the code.But the problem is I am not able to allign it to the scree in android.I mean the icon is been dragged out of view when I drag the icon at the border extreme ends.So what should I add in this code,so that the icon does not go beyond the border in android.

Comment: declare a Region object and set your view position to Region object, then put if (mRegion.contain(x,y)) it means you are in side boundry

Comment: Hi @ish can you code it please..I m doing it and still it is not responding ..so please if you can code about the thing you are saying